# How to describe parts of equations underneath them?

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows

I want to describe parts of equation underneath them similar to this:

[image]

How do I go about doing this? I have the following code so far:

```
\begin{algin}
A = \frac{B}{C} + \frac{D}{E} + \frac{G}{H}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
A = \underbrace{\frac{B}{C}}_{\substack{\text{comes}\\\text{from }X}} + 
    \underbrace{\frac{D}{E} + \frac{G}{H}}_{\substack{\text{comes}\\\text{from }Y}}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```