# Underbraces for multiplied components of an equation

Tags: math-mode

From other sources (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44834/how-to-put-a-big-bracket-under-different-parts-of-a-equation-so-that-i-could-wri) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378034/how-to-describe-parts-of-equations-underneath-them?noredirect=1&lq=1)), I have cobbled together an equation with underbraces labelling each part.

I would like to add an underbrace to this part:

```
\rm{tanh}(W_2x_t + U_2h_{t-1} + b_2)
```

but whenever I do, I get an error: Missing $ inserted.

In the comments in the MWE below, I include the code I tried that generated the error.

How can I add an underbrace to that part of the equation - it's multiplied by a term that already has an underbrace, if that's a problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
c_t = 
    \underbrace{\sigma(W_3 x_t + U_3h_{t-1} + b_3)}_\text{forget gate} c_{t-1} +
    \underbrace{\sigma(W_1x_t + U_1h_{t-1} + b_1)}_\text{input gate} \rm{tanh}(W_2x_t + U_2h_{t-1} + b_2)
\]
\end{document}

%\[
%  c_t = 
%    \underbrace{\sigma(W_3 x_t + U_3h_{t-1} + b_3)}_\text{forget gate} c_{t-1} + 
%    \underbrace{\sigma(W_1x_t + U_1h_{t-1} + b_1)}_\text{input gate} \underbrace{\rm{tanh}(W_2x_t + U_2h_{t-1} + b_2)}_\text{c_{new_t}}
%\]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `\text` expects its argument to be *text*. I.e. inside its argument you are not in math mode anymore and must add `$…$` to get the text in math mode. However since you don’t want text at all, don’t use the macro and write `\underbrace{…}_{c_{new_t}}`.

You may also like to improve your code further:

1. Use \tanh`instead of using a deprecated font macro (`\rm`). (If you need other operators, they should be defined with`\DeclareMathOperator{\tanh}{tanh}` for example.
2. Use `\text`, where it is necessary, e.g. in `c_{\text{new}_t}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% Loads amsmath

%\DeclareMathOperator{\tanh}{tanh}% already defined in that way …

\begin{document}
\[
c_t = 
    \underbrace{\sigma(W_3 x_t + U_3h_{t-1} + b_3)}_\text{forget gate} c_{t-1} +
    \underbrace{\sigma(W_1x_t + U_1h_{t-1} + b_1)}_\text{input gate} \underbrace{\tanh(W_2x_t + U_2h_{t-1} + b_2)}_{c_{\text{new}_t}}
\]
\end{document}
```